# Stuck sum subtotal mysql crosstab

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to sum total and sub total by crosstab in mysql store procedure.
I would add sub total in my script.

```
        SET @VARBRANCH='
            MAX(IF(Branch =''A'',`data`, NULL)) AS ''A'',
            MAX(IF(Branch =''B'',`data`, NULL)) AS ''B''';

            DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TBL_ACBR;
            SET @VARBRANCH=CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TBL_ACBR SELECT Prtype,SUM(data) AS Total,  '
            ,@VARBRANCH,
            ' FROM(
            SELECT Prtype, Branch, `data` FROM TBLGETDATAALL_1 GROUP BY  Branch,Prtype) t
            GROUP BY Prtype;');
            PREPARE stmacbr FROM @VARBRANCH;
            EXECUTE stmacbr;
            DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmacbr; 

            SELECT * FROM TBL_ACBR;
```

Script above  it show as the following:

```
Prtype Total  A  B
JAM     5     3  2  
Jim     5     3  3
```

The result that i need as the following:

```
Prtype Total  A  B
JAM     5     3  2  
Jim     5     3  3
Total   10    6   5
```

Comment: Try using `with rollup` it will directly give you the sum result..  Add `with rollup` at end of last group by statement. `GROUP BY Prtype with rollup`  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: @Meherzad `with rollup` will not give `6 and 5` for `A and B`.

Comment: HOw can i do if cannot  give as my result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your final select to be a union including the total.

Change:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_ACBR
```

To:

```
SELECT Prtype, Total, A, B FROM TBL_ACBR
UNION
SELECT 'Total' AS Prtype, SUM(Total), SUM(A), SUM(B) FROM TBL_ACBR
```

Comment: [Err] 1137 - Can't reopen table: 'TBL_ACBR'